# Suitable recursion for the A234289

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, recurrences

- Let $a(n)$ be [A234289](https://oeis.org/A234289) i.e. integer sequence with exponential generating function
  $$
  A(x)=1+A(x)^2\int \frac{1}{A(x)}\,dx
  $$
  The sequence begins with
  $$
  1, 1, 3, 17, 147, 1729, 25827, 468593, 10012083, 246287521, 6856204803, 213102768977
  $$
- Let
  $$
  R(n,q)=(q+1)R(n-1,q+1)+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q-1}R(n,j), \\
  R(0,q)=1
  $$

I conjecture that $$R(n,0)=a(n).$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
a(n)=local(A=1+x); for(i=1, n, A=1+A^2*intformal(1/(A+x*O(x^n)))); n!*polcoeff(A, n)
R_upto(n)=my(v1, v2, v3); v1=vector(n+1, i, 1); v2=v1; v3=vector(n+1, i, 0); v3[1]=1; for(i=1, n, for(q=0, n-i, v2[q+1]=(q+1)*v1[q+2] + sum(j=0, q-1, v2[j+1])); v1=v2; v3[i+1]=v1[1]); v3
test(n)=vector(n+1, i, a(i-1))==R_upto(n)
```

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: $\int$ stands for $\int_0^x$, I presume?

Comment: Equivalently, $A'=\dfrac{A^2}{2-A}$.